# calcultion based on items minus stock value php

Tags: php

I have a calcultion based on items minus stock value (with some community help). If it hits zero then the next row will be touched.

```
  $items = 45;
  $stockRows = [40, 50, 60];

  $newStock = function ($items, $stock) {
      foreach ($stock as &$item) {

          $delta     = $item - $items;
          $item      = $delta > 0 ? $delta : 0;
          $items = $delta < 0 ? abs($delta) : 0;
      }
      return $stock;
  };

  print_r($newStock($items, $stockRows));
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 45
    [2] => 60
)
```

Now I want to add a row identifier so that I can update the database rows afterwards in a foreach and set the correct stock amount

```
$stockRows =
array(
  array(
   'id' => 1,
   'amount' => 30
 ),
 array(
  'id' => 2,
  'amount' => 40
  ),
  array(
   'id' => 3,
   'amount' => 50
  )
);
```

I cant get this to work. And if I get a output the first array result returns id 0.

Comment: `I cant get this to work`...I don't see any attempt to create the row identifier. Show us what you tried and explain what went wrong, then we can help you fix it. That's how we do things on this site. See also [ask]. Thanks

Comment: @ADyson If I add an example or a test that does not work its has no advantage to the question. anyway fixed it myself

Comment: 'I cant get this to work' sounds like I tried things?

Comment: `If I add an example or a test that does not work its has no advantage to the question` ...no, quite the opposite. That's the **whole point of this site** - people post problems in their code, and other people try to solve them. Then if someone else is getting the same error or problem in their own code in future, they can find it, compare it to theirs, and see if the answers would help them too. Just coming along and asking for code doesn't achieve that in as efficient a way. The idea is to fix _specific_ problems / bugs which might be common in other code, not to implement features.

Comment: And it also potentially wastes the time of the volunteers here because then many people would be tempted to just ask for free code without making any effort themselves to research or try anything, which would then probably lead to a massive proliferation of freeloading and duplicate questions...and trust me, if you follow tags such as php for any length of time, you'll see there's no shortage of that kind of thing anyway, despite the site's rules.Just because you _said_ you tried something doesn't mean we can be sure you did...so that's another reason to show your attempt, even if it's no good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it myself

```
$items = 45;
$ids = [1, 2, 3];
$stockRows = [40, 50, 60];

$newStock = function ($afschrijving, $stock, $ids) {
   $i = 0;

   foreach ($stock as &$item) {

            $delta     = $item - $afschrijving;
            $item      = array($id[$i++], $delta > 0 ? $delta : 0);
            $afschrijving = $delta < 0 ? abs($delta) : 0;
        }

        return $stock;
    };

print_r($newStock($items, $stockRows, $ids));
```